# How to Get Org Record Changes in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-community

I need to Display all open cases and all open Opportunities count on Lightning Home Page based on Record changes(for example When ever a new case is opened by any other User, Lightning  home page automatically needs to update with Open Cases Count).To achieve this I have implemented Streaming API with CometD.js in Classic Version.Can any one suggest how to do the same with Lightning component without using Comet.Js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can wait a couple of days for Spring 19, you can use lightnin:empAPI to subscribe to Streaming API channels, thus it would mean you dont have to rewrite the whole wheel.

> The lightning:empApi component provides access to methods for
>   subscribing to a streaming channel and listening to event messages.
>   All streaming channels are supported, including channels for platform
>   events, PushTopic events, generic events, and Change Data Capture
>   events. The lightning:empApi component uses a shared CometD
>   connection.

Another thing is if you use [Lightning Data services(PILOT)](https://youtu.be/s7s0ha3whvM?t=324) which will automatically refresh your screen even id data change happened in Server without writing any code.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation

Comment: Will this work if I update records using DataLoader or workbench?Please confirm.

Comment: Can you please give some piece of code to achieve this with LDS or any document reference will be greatful

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Platform events to get the notification about changes on a record. After subscribing to a [Platform Event](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics) you can get the event notification using cometD.

From Documentation -

> Add the lightning:empApi component to your custom Lightning component
>   to receive platform event messages. The lightning:empApi component
>   provides access to methods for subscribing to a streaming channel and
>   listening to event messages. The lightning:empApi component uses a
>   shared CometD-based Streaming API connection, enabling you to run
>   multiple streaming apps in the browser.
>
> To call the component’s methods, add the lightning:empApi component
>   inside your custom component and assign an aura:id attribute to it.
>
> Then in the client-side
>   controller, add functions to call the component methods.

**[Subscribe to Platform Event Notifications in a Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_lc.htm)**